# how to read from and write to a csv file using csv module

Tags: python, csv

```py
import csv

with open("C:\\Users\\ki386179\\Desktop\\output.csv","r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if 'india' in row:
            pass
        if 'india' not in row:
            with open("C:\\Users\\ki386179\\Desktop\\output.csv","w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow('india')
```

I am trying to achieve something like this , to check for a particular value in a particular column  and if not write to it.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem may be you have 2 variables f. Also you're trying to write to file you have open

Comment: "to achieve something like this" - please provide what **exactly** you expect

Comment: Hi @JanStránský  Thanks for your response ,  I have a string to check in the first column of a csv file,  if it is there , i want to do nothing if it is not then i want to write at the end of the first column. all using csv modlue .. ,

Comment: What I meant by **exactly** is that you edit your question, providing sample initial state of the `output.csv` file and expected final state of the file

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is a poor way of explaining what you do want anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to a file whilst you are in the middle of reading from it. Also, surely you don't want to require *every* line to contain the string, like your current logic does?

I'm guessing you want to add one line at the end if none of the lines matched:

```py
import csv

seen_string = False

with open("C:\\Users\\ki386179\\Desktop\\output.csv","r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if 'india' in row:
            seen_string = True
            break

if not seen_string:
    # Notice append mode; "a" not "w"
    with open("C:\\Users\\ki386179\\Desktop\\output.csv","a") as f1:
        # Noice this one is f1
        writer = csv.writer(f1)
        writer.writerow('india')
```

Maybe notice also that `in` looks for a substring; if the file contains e.g. *amerindian"* the code will regard that as a match. Check for string equality with `==` instead if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `r+` mode for both reading and writing. Although it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here, an example code that can do what you're probably trying to achieve is shown below. I put the above code in a script `india.py` and made it executable (`chmod +x india.py`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from csv import reader, writer

with open(sys.argv[1], "r+") as f:
    for row in reader(f):
        if "india" in row:
            break
    else:
        writer(f).writerow("india")
```

A test run

```
$ cat test_write.csv
us,canada,mexico
france,germany,norway
brazil,argentina,colombia
china,japan,korea
$ ./india.py test_write.csv
$ cat test_write.csv
us,canada,mexico
france,germany,norway
brazil,argentina,colombia
china,japan,korea
i,n,d,i,a
```